# Search plist for integer

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist

In an iOS app, I take a four digit code from the user and give them a corresponding string in a TextView. My question is, because there are about a thousand possible codes the user would enter that I am checking for, what is an efficient way to give a result without having a huge if or switch statement? Like, using a plist, txt file, or even database.... Thanks in advance

Comment: There are 10,000 possible four-digit codes, not 1,000.

Comment: I understand that, but for this app only some of them would be logical; i.e. the user would not want to enter certain ranges of numbers because they would not make sense (range of 2400-2900 is not used). I understand that 10000 are POSSIBLE, but I only need to make corresponding strings for the 1000 or so that actually make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision of plist, text file or database is just a matter of storage, not search. Personally, I would just use a JSON file, since it's reasonably well-supported both by the human brain and by software. For searching, just put them in an NSDictionary and do a lookup on that. Unless your items are very big, 1000 items is not really a large dataset, even on a memory-constrained iPhone. Even if each item is 1 KB (which sounds a lot larger than the dataset you're describing), you're looking at less than a megabyte for the whole set.

If the strings happen to be long, then store the long text in a file and store the file URL in your lookup table instead of the whole string. IIRC, a URL is about 100 bytes on average, and an NSNumber is about 8, so you'd be looking at about 108 KB for the entire dataset.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSON files, but I will look into them

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of possible codes I would recommend [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). Alternatively you can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) directly. You *could* use a plist, but I fear it would quickly become unmanageable as you add, remove, and update codes.